# How does Dart leverage SOAP requests?

Tags: soap, dart

I was looking up how to do SOAP requests within Dart.  When looking at HTTPRequest it really only mentions RESTful services and wanted to make sure that this can be done.

Right now, I have my server, username, and password.  Trying to get a successful authentication via the service, so that way I have an auth token i can pass when doing subsequent calls.

It seems for example in .NET, it does the following and then stores the credential in a server side session variable which I was using as a starting point to make this in Dart.

```
// create web service api object
WebServiceAPI api = new WebServiceAPI();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyUserName"]))
{
    System.Net.NetworkCredential nc = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyUserName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyPassword"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProxyDomain"]);
    System.Net.CredentialCache cc = new System.Net.CredentialCache();
    cc.Add(new Uri(api.Url), "NTLM", nc);
    api.Credentials = cc;
}

api.AuthenticateCredential("api@admin", "admin", 0, 0);
HttpContext.Current.Session["api"] = api;
```

**Edit:**  I am adding some sample data such that if there is a hack we can leverage to get something working, we might be able to abstract it and genericize.

```
service asmx file:  
http://127.0.0.1:1337/service.asmx

Method we will be calling: (AuthenticateCredential)
http://127.0.0.1:1337/service.asmx?op=AuthenticateCredential

The sample SOAP request:
POST /service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://foo.com/bar/320/Default/AuthenticateCredential"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <AuthenticateCredential xmlns="http://foo.com/barr/320/Default">
      <UserName>string</UserName>
      <Password>string</Password>
      <CurrentSystemLoginID>int</CurrentSystemLoginID>
      <CurrentCustomerID>int</CurrentCustomerID>
    </AuthenticateCredential>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

then naturally, I will have to write up and mod the `string,string,int,int` out of the envelope. such that the credentials are correct.

Comment: Just out of interest, what service are you trying to work with, and what authentication protocol does it use? Have you looked to see if it supports different web services styles?

Comment: It has Basic Authentication, which i am slowly working with.  Since it is an ASMX file, im inclined to believe it is a C#/ASP webservice i am trying to connect to, which handles a sample database for later use

Comment: That's HTTP basic authentication then, so you could handle auth at the HTTP level.

Comment: Where to put the values I need to submit like I want to post username="Naham" and password="123456"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've performed SOAP actions for Blackboard's web services using Dart, so it's possible.  To do so, I had to build the SOAP envelope programmatically for each request.  The requests themselves were sent using the http package's 'post' method.

Can't say how your requests should be set up, that would depend on the web service you're attempting to access.  For the HTTP headers, I sent a 'Content-Type' of 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' and a 'SOAPAction' header specifying the SOAP method.  The body was the full SOAP envelope.

You may need to play around a bit to build the envelope with the correct format/info your service expects.  I used the xml package to parse/interpret the responses.

Comment: Is it possible for you to elaborate by giving a sound example of a soap request and your restful resolution?  I can give you some sample data given my WSDL if it helps you.

Comment: <pre><code>
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:xml/xml.dart' as xml;

// Build out SOAP envelope (dependent on your service)
var envelope = '<soap-env:Envelope ... > ... </soap-env:Envelope>';

// Send the POST request
http.Response response = await http.post (
  'http://someurl/someservice',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    'SOAPAction': 'someSoapMethod'
  },
  body: envelope
);

// Response as raw XML
var rawXmlResponse = response.body;

// parse the response
xml.XmlDocument parsedXml = xml.parse (rawXmlResponse);
</code></pre>

Comment: This may be easier, I couldn't get the format to work right in the comment:

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/c9dd7c713cbf48d3ea32

Comment: Ill give you sample data via a question Edit, then can you edit your response and include the dartlang and the code snippet using sample data?

Comment: Here's a new DartPad with the info you edited:

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/2561dd3579e45d1eb730

I notice you did not have a header in your SOAP envelope.  By the SOAP spec, I believe this is optional, but depending on your service, it may be required and expect some particular setup/fields.

Comment: mm.  It seems that given your example, it does not like:  `http.response = await http.post`

Comment: this is the result of your calls:  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: AuthenticateCredential.</faultstring>
      <detail />
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`  ***Server Did not recognize SOAPAction***

Comment: im curious if *SOAPAction* is a standardized component

Comment: updated SOAPAction via WSDL, and got this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header>
    <BasicAuthenticationToken xmlns="http://foo.com/bar/320/Default" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <AuthenticateCredentialResponse xmlns="http://marshal.com/spe/320/Default">
      <AuthenticateCredentialResult>false</AuthenticateCredentialResult>
    </AuthenticateCredentialResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`

Comment: my bet is that, while it was successful, the authentication was not correct.

Comment: Looks like SOAPAction isn't supported for your service (can't remember why I needed it in my work), but not having that, you're well on your way to getting this to work.  Best of luck!

Comment: You may find it easier to get a request working with a free SOAP testing tool such as SOAPUI, then write the code to make the same request

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no solution for that. There are only limited XML packages for Dart and I haven't seen attempts to implement SOAP itself.
A possible workaround would be to delegate to a server written in another language that forwards REST calls as SOAP calls.

Comment: While I was looking around the dev website and also stackoverflow, I noticed that you said that a year or so ago to another user.  I was not sure if it was still relevant or if there were secret packages which handled this.

Comment: There might be but I monitor the Dart area pretty close and can't remember seen anything mentioned.

Comment: IS the situation with SOAP still same in 2021

Comment: I'm not aware of changes, but I haven't followed that closely since a while.