# Flutter SOAP: How to using SOAP in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub

How to using SOAP Api calls in Flutter? I have tried rest calls is working fine. I need to build SOAP calls in flutter. Kindly share how to call SOAP in flutter

Comment: It seems there is no complete solution for that yet. Good news is that it's still possible to make SOAP calls on your own. Here in comments, you may see some samples how to do that - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35157186/1010710

Answer (score 6, accepted):

refer this link sucessfully call SOAP https://dartpad.dartlang.org/2561dd3579e45d1eb730

```
void functionCall() async {
    var envelope = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetAllCity xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
''';

    http.Response response = await http.post(
        'http://www.i2isoftwares.com/SSKSService/sskss.asmx',
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
          "SOAPAction": "http://tempuri.org/GetAllCity",
          "Host": "www.i2isoftwares.com"
          //"Accept": "text/xml"
        },
        body: envelope);

    var rawXmlResponse = response.body;

// Use the xml package's 'parse' method to parse the response.
    xml.XmlDocument parsedXml = xml.parse(rawXmlResponse);

    print("DATAResult=" + response.body);
  }
```

Comment: I try to user code but didn't work. I have similar project and I couldn't build envelope because its very complex. I had wsdl document and help with xmlspy I get the xml part that I need to work. But it doesn't look like your example, any help